# Yocto Toaster won't build image

Tags: python, yocto

I can't make Yocto Toaster make any image. When I try to build using bitbake, everything work as expected. Toaster als start without any warning or errors, but when I start build I always receive error:

```
Error executing a python function in <code>:

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:
File: '<code>', lineno: 4, function: <module>
     0001:__anon_22__home_gpufler_poky__toaster_clones__git___git_yoctoproject_org_poky_master_meta_conf_machine_include_arm_feature_arm_thumb_inc(d)
     0002:__anon_25__home_gpufler_poky__toaster_clones__git___git_yoctoproject_org_poky_master_meta_classes_patch_bbclass(d)
     0003:__anon_160__home_gpufler_poky__toaster_clones__git___git_yoctoproject_org_poky_master_meta_classes_base_bbclass(d)
 *** 0004:__anon_686__home_gpufler_poky__toaster_clones__git___git_yoctoproject_org_poky_master_meta_classes_base_bbclass(d)
     0005:__anon_1312__home_gpufler_poky__toaster_clones__git___git_yoctoproject_org_poky_master_meta_classes_insane_bbclass(d)
     0006:__anon_250__home_gpufler_poky__toaster_clones__git___git_yoctoproject_org_poky_master_meta_classes_package_bbclass(d)
     0007:__anon_707__home_gpufler_poky__toaster_clones__git___git_yoctoproject_org_poky_master_meta_classes_package_rpm_bbclass(d)
     0008:__anon_25__home_gpufler_poky__toaster_clones__git___git_yoctoproject_org_poky_master_meta_classes_debian_bbclass(d)
File: '/home/gpufler/poky/_toaster_clones/_git___git.yoctoproject.org_poky_master/meta/classes/base.bbclass', lineno: 587, function: __anon_686__home_gpufler_poky__toaster_clones__git___git_yoctoproject_org_poky_master_meta_classes_base_bbclass
     0583:    needsrcrev = False
     0584:    srcuri = d.getVar('SRC_URI')
     0585:    for uri in srcuri.split():
     0586:        (scheme, _ , path) = bb.fetch.decodeurl(uri)[:3]
 *** 0587:
     0588:        # HTTP/FTP use the wget fetcher
     0589:        if scheme in ("http", "https", "ftp"):
     0590:            d.appendVarFlag('do_fetch', 'depends', ' wget-native:do_populate_sysroot')
     0591:
File: '/home/gpufler/poky/_toaster_clones/_git___git.yoctoproject.org_poky_master/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py', lineno: 368, function: decodeurl
     0364:    """
     0365:
     0366:    m = re.compile('(?P<type>[^:]*)://((?P<user>[^/;]+)@)?(?P<location>[^;]+)(;(?P<parm>.*))?').match(url)
     0367:    if not m:
 *** 0368:        raise MalformedUrl(url)
     0369:
     0370:    type = m.group('type')
     0371:    location = m.group('location')
     0372:    if not location:
Exception: bb.fetch2.MalformedUrl: The URL: '${MISC_GIT_URI}/${MISC_GIT_PREFIX}qemu.git;protocol=${MISC_GIT_PROTOCOL};branch=stable-2.1' is invalid and cannot be interpreted
```

Any idea?

THX
Goran

Comment: Are you trying to compile Qemu?  how you got this error. using bitbake or toaster

Comment: For this example yes, originally I was trying to build core-image-minimal for beaglebone black or RaspberryPI, but I get the same error. This is with Toaster, with bitbake everything works fine.

Comment: could you provide the screenshot of toaster. i thought you added machine variable in toaster. am I Right? and tell me the yocto version?

Comment: Here is complete log, I need to figure out where to put picture :)